# How to optimise the solution to not get memory limit exceeded error or what might be getting me the error?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, depth-first-search

I came across the following problem.

```
You are given the root of a binary tree with n nodes. 
Each node is uniquely assigned a value from 1 to n. 
You are also given an integer startValue representing 
the value of the start node s, 
and a different integer destValue representing 
the value of the destination node t.

Find the shortest path starting from node s and ending at node t. 
Generate step-by-step directions of such path as a string consisting of only the 
uppercase letters 'L', 'R', and 'U'. Each letter indicates a specific direction:

'L' means to go from a node to its left child node.
'R' means to go from a node to its right child node.
'U' means to go from a node to its parent node.
Return the step-by-step directions of the shortest path from node s to node t
```

Example 1:
[image]

```
Input: root = [5,1,2,3,null,6,4], startValue = 3, destValue = 6
Output: "UURL"
Explanation: The shortest path is: 3 → 1 → 5 → 2 → 6.
```

Example 2:

[image]

```
Input: root = [2,1], startValue = 2, destValue = 1
Output: "L"
Explanation: The shortest path is: 2 → 1.
```

I created the solution by finding the least common ancestor and then doing a depth-first-search to find the elements, Like this:-

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution(object):
    def getDirections(self, root, startValue, destValue):
        """
        :type root: Optional[TreeNode]
        :type startValue: int
        :type destValue: int
        :rtype: str
        """

        def lca(root):
            if root == None or root.val == startValue or root.val == destValue:
                return root
        
            left = lca(root.left)
            right = lca(root.right)
        
            if left and right:
                return root
        
            return left or right
    
        def dfs(root, value, path):
            if root == None:
                return ""
        
            if root.val == value:
                return path
        
            return dfs(root.left, value, path + "L") + dfs(root.right, value, path + "R")
        
        
        root = lca(root)
        return "U"*len(dfs(root, startValue, "")) + dfs(root, destValue, "")
```

The solution runs good, however for a very large input it throws "Memory Limit Exceeded" error, can anyone tell me how I can optimise the solution, or what might I be doing that could be getting me into it ?

Comment: What environment and how large is the input?

Comment: As the tree is given as list you can just find indexes of start and dest in it. As long as start index is greater than dest index, set start index to parent of current start and note a "U" for beginning, If dest is greater, go up to parent of dest and note "L" or "R" depending where dest came from. When indexes are equal, take "U"s plus the reverse of the "L"-"R" sequence as final result. Fine tuning may be necessary.

Comment: The first step is to learn about the [array-based **heap** data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)). The input to your program is an array that is organized like a **heap**. It takes a linear search to find the two nodes. But once found, the index of the node tells you how deep that node is, and it indicates whether the node is a left child or a right child. So the solution is to start with the deeper node, go up until the both nodes are at the same level, and then continue up until the nodes meet at the common ancestor.

Comment: @user3386109 OP did not specify if this was a complete balanced binary tree, so this approach does not work

Comment: @JacobSteinebronn You are incorrect. You apparently missed the `null` in the input in the first example.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Lists don't have `.left` etc, so the list is clearly just the input for the judge code, not the `root` argument the function gets. (And the docstring also says its type is `Optional[TreeNode]`.)

Comment: @user3386109 It's **not** organized like a heap. For example, `[1,2,null,3,null,4]` is a left-leaning tree of height 4, as [the visualizer will show you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sdYq.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting a memory limit exceeded is the arguments to the `dfs` function. Your 'path' variable is a string that can be as large as the height of the tree (which can be the size of the whole tree if it's unbalanced).

Normally that wouldn't be a problem, but `path + "L"` creates a new string for every recursive call of the function. Besides being very slow, this means that your memory usage is `O(n^2)`, where `n` is the number of nodes in the tree.

For example, if your final path is `"L" * 1000`, your call stack for `dfs` will look like this:

```py
Depth 0: dfs(root, path = "")
Depth 1: dfs(root.left, path = "L")
Depth 2: dfs(root.left.left, path = "LL")
...
Depth 999:  path = "L"*999
Depth 1000:  path = "L"*1000
```

Despite all those variables being called `path`, they are all completely different strings, for a total memory usage of `~(1000*1000)/2 = 500,000` characters at one time. With one million nodes, this is half a trillion characters.

Now, this doesn't happen just because strings are immutable; in fact, **even if you were using lists** (which are mutable), you'd still have this problem, as `path + ["L"]` would still be forced to create a copy of `path`.

To solve this, you need to have exactly one variable for the `path` stored outside of the `dfs` function, and only append to it from the recursive `dfs` function. This will ensure you only ever use `O(n)` space.

```py
def dfs(root, value, path):
    if root is None:
        return False

    if root.val == value:
        return True

    if dfs(root.left, value, path):
        path.append("L")
        return True
    elif dfs(root.right, value, path):
        path.append("R")
        return True
    return False

root = lca(root)
start_to_root = []
dfs(root, startValue, start_to_root)

dest_to_root = []
dfs(root, destValue, dest_to_root)

return "U" * len(start_to_root) + ''.join(reversed(dest_to_root))
```

Comment: "With one million nodes, this is half a trillion characters" - I wanna see the system that allows Python recursion a million deep :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy True, I overlooked that. The better solution is probably just iterative DFS, where we pop and append to our path as we search the tree, although its slightly more complex to code.

Comment: Meh, [it's a LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/step-by-step-directions-from-a-binary-tree-node-to-another/), and they're not that nasty that they'd make a recursive solution impossible. I'm pretty sure they also increased the recursion limit, as they're not limiting memory so much that the standard limit 1000 would lead to the memory limit being exceeded.

Comment: I just checked that, `sys.getrecursionlimit()` shows they've set it to 550000, and `if len(path) % 1000 == 0: print(len(path))` at the start of the `dfs` function shows the length going up to 46000. At which point the strings take about 1 GB, so apparently that's how much memory LeetCode allows.